# Update this code table

Tags: tables

I am a new latex user and I have written the following table code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|c{1.5cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{\textcolor{red}{Proportional}}&\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_D$}}\\\cline{2-9}
        \textbf{\textcolor{red}{layer}}&\textbf{0}&\textbf{0.1}&\textbf{0.2}&\textbf{0.3}&\textbf{0.4}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{6}\\\hline
        \textbf{daisy-chain}&136&148&157&167&173&304&424&544\\\hline
        \textbf{Net1}&136&140&140&142&145&220&313&373\\\hline
        \textbf{tree}&136&126&123&104&\textbf{93}&211&315&436\\\hline
        \textbf{ring}&136&147&154&165&170&304&424&536\\\hline
        \textbf{star-1}&136&134&146&162&175&389&607&\textbf{771}\\\hline
        \textbf{wheel}&136&149&160&167&173&381&601&765\\\hline
        \textbf{neighb135}&136&149&162&166&182&390&594&762\\\hline
        \textbf{Net2}&136&133&138&135&146&392&524&605\\\hline
        \textbf{Net3}&136&142&144&146&167&401&538&686\\\hline
        \textbf{all-to-all}&136&145&149&154&170&408&554&713\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
```

[image]

How can I modify this code to increase the width of all the columns with numbers?

Comment: Hi, can you reword your question and/or ask google to translate from your original language?

Comment: You can redefine the length `\tabcolsep` which defines the padding between tabular cells.

Comment: B.t.w., if you want maths in boldface, writing `\textbf` is of no use. For maths, you should write `\multicolumn{8}{c}{\boldmath$\sigma_D$}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To benefit from all the available width (`\textwidth`), you can use the `tabularx` package. The first column is set left justified whereas all the remaining horizontal space is shared among the number columns.

Also, to center the `x` columns, you can define a new column-type like this:

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

with the aid of the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,color,array}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{8}{Y}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{\textcolor{red}{Proportional}}&\multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{$\sigma_D$}}\\\cline{2-9}
    \textbf{\textcolor{red}{layer}}&\textbf{0}&\textbf{0.1}&\textbf{0.2}&\textbf{0.3}&\textbf{0.4}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{6}\\\hline
    \textbf{daisy-chain}&136&148&157&167&173&304&424&544\\\hline
    \textbf{Net1}&136&140&140&142&145&220&313&373\\\hline
    \textbf{tree}&136&126&123&104&\textbf{93}&211&315&436\\\hline
    \textbf{ring}&136&147&154&165&170&304&424&536\\\hline
    \textbf{star-1}&136&134&146&162&175&389&607&\textbf{771}\\\hline
    \textbf{wheel}&136&149&160&167&173&381&601&765\\\hline
    \textbf{neighb135}&136&149&162&166&182&390&594&762\\\hline
    \textbf{Net2}&136&133&138&135&146&392&524&605\\\hline
    \textbf{Net3}&136&142&144&146&167&401&538&686\\\hline
    \textbf{all-to-all}&136&145&149&154&170&408&554&713\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A better way is to use the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,color,array,booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{8}{Y}@{}}
    \toprule
    &\multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{$\sigma_D$}}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-9}
    \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{\parbox{6.7em}{Proportional layer}}}}&\textbf{0}&\textbf{0.1}&\textbf{0.2}&\textbf{0.3}&\textbf{0.4}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{6}\\\midrule
    \textbf{daisy-chain}&136&148&157&167&173&304&424&544\\
    \textbf{Net1}&136&140&140&142&145&220&313&373\\
    \textbf{tree}&136&126&123&104&\textbf{93}&211&315&436\\
    \textbf{ring}&136&147&154&165&170&304&424&536\\
    \textbf{star-1}&136&134&146&162&175&389&607&\textbf{771}\\
    \textbf{wheel}&136&149&160&167&173&381&601&765\\
    \textbf{neighb135}&136&149&162&166&182&390&594&762\\
    \textbf{Net2}&136&133&138&135&146&392&524&605\\
    \textbf{Net3}&136&142&144&146&167&401&538&686\\
    \textbf{all-to-all}&136&145&149&154&170&408&554&713\\\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you update this code for have the number at center of the cell???

Comment: @LucaAngelino - Yes, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*8{p{1cm}}|}
\hline
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{Proportional}}&\multicolumn{8}{c|}{\textbf{$\sigma_D$}}\\\cline{2-9}
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{layer}}&\textbf{0}&\textbf{0.1}&\textbf{0.2}&\textbf{0.3}&\textbf{0.4}&\textbf{2}&\textbf{4}&\textbf{6}\\\hline
\textbf{daisy-chain}&136&148&157&167&173&304&424&544\\\hline
\textbf{Net1}&136&140&140&142&145&220&313&373\\\hline
\textbf{tree}&136&126&123&104&\textbf{93}&211&315&436\\\hline
\textbf{ring}&136&147&154&165&170&304&424&536\\\hline
\textbf{star-1}&136&134&146&162&175&389&607&\textbf{771}\\\hline
\textbf{wheel}&136&149&160&167&173&381&601&765\\\hline
\textbf{neighb135}&136&149&162&166&182&390&594&762\\\hline
 \textbf{Net2}&136&133&138&135&146&392&524&605\\\hline
\textbf{Net3}&136&142&144&146&167&401&538&686\\\hline
\textbf{all-to-all}&136&145&149&154&170&408&554&713\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: simltbl]